# Mark objects or texts as "not printable" on Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

Is possible I define an object or text as "not printable"? So, for instance, I can see it on document, but it'll not printed on paper.

I need put some pictures on document that is useful only as marker, but is not useful to print.

Comment: Options > Display contains only [global options](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BIVwu.png), but maybe someone knows how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is it possible to make an object or text "not printable"?

You can use hidden text for this. For an image attach it to the hidden text using an image anchor.

Then configure word to display hidden text and turn off printing hidden text.

[image]